# Mount EXT4 partition from former RAID1 disk Member on Synology NAS

Tags: usb, mount, raid

I am trying to recover the data from a single member of a RAID1 set that was in my poorly engineered Synology DS220J that now is in the trash can due to lack of warranty and failed power supply. I was never able to rebuild the mirror set with the replaced drive so now I am just trying to manually recover the data from the single drive. Since Synology formatted it with EXT4 I booted over to Ubuntu from Windows and stuck it in a USB3 SATA controller. I see it in the "disks" app and I see it using `sudo lshw`

```
     *-scsi:3
          physical id: d
          logical name: scsi6
        *-disk:0
             description: SCSI Disk
             product: Dual SATA Bridge
             vendor: Sabrent
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@6:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sdd
             version: 0
             serial: 00000000000000000000
             size: 5589GiB (6001GB)
             capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             configuration: ansiversion=6 guid=3e4e6f03-2149-4821-bbec-e3648ab1111c logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
           *-volume:0
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@6:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sdd1
                version: 1.0
                serial: e61a6158-2439-4b77-ad68-f39f55c1079d
                size: 2431MiB
                capacity: 2431MiB
                capabilities: multi journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2023-05-01 12:06:59 filesystem=ext4 label=1.42.6-25426 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2023-06-20 19:01:04 mounted=2023-06-20 19:01:04 state=clean
           *-volume:1
                description: Linux swap volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@6:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sdd2
                version: 1
                serial: c14fce3a-f785-4ded-af6a-ec6b85487bbd
                size: 2047MiB
                capacity: 2047MiB
                capabilities: multi swap initialized
                configuration: filesystem=swap pagesize=4096
           *-volume:2
                description: RAID partition
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 5
                bus info: scsi@6:0.0.0,5
                logical name: /dev/sdd5
                serial: a4f5f484-eba9-4d38-9135-83687766591e
                capacity: 5584GiB
                capabilities: multi
```

It's that last bit with the 5.5GB

I can't mount it:

```
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sdd5 usb3                                                                                                                                                                                                                ─╯
mount: /home/nate/usb3: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdd5, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

and I can't mdadm it:

```
sudo mdadm --assemble --readonly ext4 /dev/sdd5 usb3                                                                                                                                                                                             ─╯
mdadm: /dev/sdd5 is busy - skipping
mdadm: cannot open device usb3: Invalid argument
mdadm: usb3 has no superblock - assembly aborted
```

What can I do to get to the data on that drive? Surely it's still there.

Side note: usb3 is a directory under my home dir.

Other info:

```
sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdd5                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ─╯
/dev/sdd5:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 3a7583b2:05793d15:cff6a40c:fbad9c4a
           Name : SynologyNAS:2
  Creation Time : Thu Nov  5 15:59:57 2020
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 11711382912 (5584.42 GiB 5996.23 GB)
     Array Size : 5855691456 (5584.42 GiB 5996.23 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=1968 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : cf1a234b:e6973349:c3cc71ae:294570f6

    Update Time : Tue Jun 20 19:30:14 2023
       Checksum : 5ca6bbb8 - correct
         Events : 200438


   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing
```

and

```
sdd                       8:48   0   5.5T  0 disk  
├─sdd1                    8:49   0   2.4G  0 part  
├─sdd2                    8:50   0     2G  0 part  
└─sdd5                    8:53   0   5.5T  0 part  
  └─osprober-linux-sdd5 253:0    0   5.5T  1 dm    
    └─md2                 9:2    0   5.5T  1 raid1
```

more:

```
sudo mdadm --assemble --run /dev/md0 /dev/sdd5 --force                                                                                                                                                                                           ─╯
mdadm: /dev/sdd5 is busy - skipping
```

ugh

```
sudo mdadm --stop /dev/sdd5                                                                                                                                                                                                                      ─╯
mdadm: /dev/sdd5 does not appear to be an md device
```

wtf

```
╰─ sudo cat /proc/mdstat                                                                                                                                                                                                                            ─╯
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md2 : inactive sdd5[2](S)
      5855691456 blocks super 1.2
       
unused devices: <none>
```

Everything is obnoxiously dysfunctional in my special case. Nothing ever works for me especially if it works for everyone else in the whole world.

```
sudo mdadm --examine --scan >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf                                                                                                                                                                                             ─╯
zsh: permission denied: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

The above was fixed by doing it as the root user instead of sudo. None of what has worked in this scenario for others, has worked for me.

```
sudo mount /dev/md2 usb3 -o ro                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ─╯
mount: /home/nate/usb3: can't read superblock on /dev/md2
```

I give up